# What is the origin of the waypoint CLAWW and PAHTI(New England region)?

Tags: waypoint

I'm the reading the book "Sayfaring". 
There are two waypoints I don't get the origins in the sentences.

1) CLAWW

"Boston has lifted a particularly intricate constellation of itself
into the ether above New England. There is PLGRM, for the
region’s history; CHWDH, LBSTA and CLAWW for its food"

2) PAHTI

"Even the region’s speech –WIKID, followed by PAHTI – seems to be mapped

Comment: Aha. Someone finds some interest in Bosron-talk.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I'm from the home of the pilgrim fathers so the lingo is familiar ;)  I'm also a "foodie" so New England sea food is no stranger to me.

Comment: Related: [A Pilot Explains Waypoints](http://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2015-06-02/a-pilot-explains-waypoints-the-hidden-geography-of-the-sky)

Comment: Somewhere in the basement of the FAA charting office is one person, a bag of Scrabble letter tiles, a 5-tile template, and a bottle of cheap booze - we're talking plastic bottle vodka. ". . . . And that's how waypoints are named!"

Answer (score 6):

Read it as "wicked party" and Boston is famous for sea food, including crab claws.  Chowder, lobster and claws.

Comment: Yup, that is correct.

Comment: A reference to the Boston Tea ***Party***, perhaps?

Comment: @RalphJ Bahstn's fahst wicked pahti!

Comment: You might wanna emphasize the [R dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English#United_States) in Boston :D

Comment: @SMSvonderTann you don't have an APPLE waypoint in Boston? proceed direct APPLE, how do you like them apples :D

Comment: @ymb1 Nope, that waypoint is in the LGA/JFK area.

Comment: @ymb1 Yup, have heard that before.